# Is there any reason why the moduli and axion fields are not observable in string theory?

Tags: string-theory

One of the biggest criticisms put forth by the common skeptics of string theory is that we don't observe the moduli and axion fields that the theory predicts, and so we have to hide these fields so the theory doesn't conflict with observation. But, is there any reason WHY these fields are unobservable in string theory?

http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2018/05/dear-dr-b-should-i-study-string-theory.html?m=1

Here is a reference that contains the criticism.

Comment: Do you have a source that this is one of the biggest criticisms? Since string theory is supposed to work at energy scales such that all know particles are massless, the axion can easily fit into any current axion model.

Comment: I have no idea what the intention of this question is. Are you asking how string theorists "hide" these fields in order to match reality? Are you asking us to come up with new reasons why they would be invisible?

Comment: @mitchell porter I’m asking if there is any mechanism to hide these fields to explain why we don’t see them. Instead of just saying that we don’t for some reason.

Comment: OK. Well, in models that are meant to be realistic, they say we don't see them because they are heavy and/or because they decay, or they say we do see them and they are part of the dark matter. But the details are highly model-dependent.